# MIC not working in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, pulseaudio, skype, alsa, microphone

Internal MIC not working in my Ubuntu 14.10 and it was worked in all previous Ubuntu versions.

Tested with Skype, Kazam and Hangout.

**Sound Settings**

[image]

**pavucontrol**

[image]

**alsamixer**

[image]

**gstreamer-properties**

[image]

gsteamer gives this warning also:

```
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'artsdsink'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'esdsink'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sunaudiosink'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'glimagesink'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sdlvideosink'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'v4lmjpegsrc'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'qcamsrc'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'v4lsrc'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'esdmon'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sunaudiosrc'
```